# Where does "Add XY Coordinates" tool get data from?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, lidar, las, xyz

I am using the ArcGIS `Add XY Coordinates` tool to populate XYZ values in a shapefile after converting .las data to .shp using `LAS to Multipoint` tool.

Does the `Add XY Coordinates` tool get the location info from the LAS dataset OR is it getting it from the data frame somehow?

I need to make sure I am getting the actual data from the LAS files because, I will eventually convert the shapefiles dbf to a .pts file to do some other calcs outside of ArcGIS.

Also, is there a better way of getting XYZ from LAS in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an LAS to Multipoint tool to import .las files in to ArcMap.

Add XY is getting the XY/Z values from your file that you feed into it.

From [Adding x,y coordinate data as a layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm):

> In addition to data sources, such as a shapefile, you can add tabular
>   data that contains geographic locations in the form of x,y coordinates
>   to your map. If the table also contains z-coordinates, such as
>   elevation values, you can add tabular data as 3D content into your
>   globe or scene.

If you open your .las file in a text editor, you will see the many x, y & z values for your point cloud. This is what is being read using the Add XY tool.

Comment: I have tried opening the .las files in notepad and notepad++ but both applications display a garbled mess of characters. Is there something else I should be doing to display them in a text editor?

Answer (score 2):

The 'Add XY Coordinates' tool is generally meant for adding coordinate fields to  data tables already in arcmap. If you've already converted your .LAS to a .SHP then you should be able to add that to your data frame as-is without any special import procedure. It will already have a SHAPE column which has the XY info in it. If you want to expose the X & Y coordinates explicitly in your table (ie, add new columns) then this is the tool for you.
   Alternatively there is the 'Add XY Data' tool which does more what you're thinking; that is, add data from an existing table into a new layer by telling ArcMap which are the X & Y fields. However, it sounds like you've already done the conversion and are just looking to expose the XY data in ArcMap.

I can't speak to working with .LAS in ArcMap specifically but did dig up a few links for you:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/what-is-a-las-dataset-.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm

Comment: I think you're confusing the Add XY Coordinates tool and the Add XY Data 'tool' (and it's confusing, I agree). The former adds fields to an attribute table and populates them with the data's coordinates. The Add XY Data tool takes a file like text or csv and creates a layer from the xy coordinate values.

Comment: Ah true enough ... both deal with tabular data though do they not?